# Injective function on $\Bbb Z^2$ that preserves the $l_1$ distance

Tags: functions

I am looking for a function $f : \Bbb Z^2 \to \Bbb Z^2$ with the following properties:

1. $f$ is injective
2. $d_{l_1}(z, z') = \lambda \cdot d_{l_1} (f(z), f(z'))$ for some constant $\lambda$. I.e. $f$ preservers the $l_1$ distance up to some constant factor.
3. If $f(x,y) = (a,b)$ and $f(x', y') = (a', b')$ then $x = x' $ or (exclusive) $y = y' \implies a \ne a' ∧ b \ne b'$. I.e. if two points share the same $x$ coordinate or $y$ coordinate, then they are mapped to points that do not share either coordinate.

Can such a function exist? If so, what does it look like? Would it make a difference if $f: S \to \Bbb Z^2$ where $S$ is a finite subset of $\Bbb Z^2$?

Comment: I edited my question to make this more clear.

Comment: When you say $l_1$ distance, do you mean the metric? Because then you would say either $$d(x,y)=\lambda \cdot d(f(x),f(y))$$ or $$d((x,y),(a,b))=\lambda \cdot d(f(x,y),f(a,b))$$And just to be clear, this is the Manhattan / taxicab metric, right?

Comment: I meant the former, I had written it incorrectly and I edited the question now. Yes, I mean the Manhattan metric.

Comment: Ah, in that case, the rule should not apply since both points would be equal. I see what you mean now. Yes, it should be XOR.